# Function of a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes

Say I'm given a probability space.
I need to define a function that looks at a $\sigma$-algebra and outputs a number.

For example, fix a set $B\subseteq\Omega$.
A simple function would be to output 1 if the $\sigma$-algebra contains $B$ and zero otherwise.

I am interested in other (more complicated) functions, but I was shaky when trying to write formally the definitions. Could somebody provide a reference where they deal with objects like this?

I am ultimately interested in something more, which is a function of a filtration, but I guess the jump is easy once I fully understand the previous.

Cheers

Comment: I think this might be a bit broad.

Comment: Any measure on the sigma algebra is an example, but there are all kinds of other functions.